# Inject variables into function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ho do i call a function injecting into its scope arbitrary variables / functions? I want to define an "update" function that can freely call a series of functions, but they have to be defined and bond in another scope.

I tried with `with` but it doesn't work.

Also, I know there are a tons of solutions like passing the object whose functions to call or define a list of arguments and bind them, but since "update" has to be defined by the user, its signature must be just a simple function with no arguments (just like in the code below) but it has to have access to a long list of functions with an arbitrary binding.

So basically: the update() function must not contain any argument in its signature and within it the functions have to be callable just with their names (no this.printSize(), obj.printSize() and so so).

```js
function obj (size) {
    this.printSize = function () {
        console.log(size);
    }
}

const obj1 = new obj(1);
const obj2 = new obj(2);

function update () {
    printSize();
}

with(obj1) {
    update();
}

with(obj2) {
    update();
}
```

Comment: With apply I have to specify the available functions in the signature of update(), but, as specified, the signature must be empty.

Comment: No, you would just need to modify update to do `this.printSize();` instead of `printSize();` and then call e.g. `update.apply(obj1);`

Comment: Hi and thanks. Please, see the edit

Comment: _"but since "update" has to be defined by the user, its signature must be just a simple function with no arguments"_ Can the user supplied function be adjusted after provided by user?

Comment: Why not let the user declare the function in a scope that has all these variables? Or, assuming the user writes his function as text somewhere, just wrap it automatically in such an environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewer discretion is advised:

```js
function evalWith(obj, func) {
  with(obj) return eval('(' + func + ')')();
}

// Example:
function obj(size) {
  this.printSize = function() {
    console.log(size);
  }
}

const obj1 = new obj(1);

function update() {
  printSize();
}

evalWith(obj1, update); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable binding in javascript is set upon function *creation*, not calling.

So, your only effective options are to namespace the variables you need in an object, and populate that later. Or you can set the variables to the global namespace (e.g) window.

There's no way to get the contents of a function and re-eval it later, unfortunately.

The most you can do is change the values of the arguments passed into the function, using call or apply as mentioned by others.

Comment: "*There's no way to get the contents of a function and re-eval it later*" - [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)?

Comment: TIL function.toString returns the contents of that function. *shudder*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
function obj (size) {
    this.printSize = function () {
        // presumably do something with "this"
        console.log(size);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does your suggestion still implies using "with" or are you suggesting to inject the variables of "obj" in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an instance of the obj before each with call

```js
function obj (size) {
    printSize = function () {
        console.log(size);
    }
}




function update () {
    printSize();
}

const obj1 = new obj(1);

with(obj1) {

    update();
}

const obj2 = new obj(2);

with(obj2) {

    update();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As specified, I cannot pass arguments to update() and the functions must be called unattached to any object (this., obj. etc), hence the need to "inject functions into the scope)

Comment: Hi, thanks again. How is your code different from mine? They seem identical and mine is giving me an error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: this.printSize 'this' will make the function implies to the obj function only, So your code will throw printSize is not defined as it cant see printsize function.

Comment: Since *printSize* is not declared in the *obj* function, each time *obj* is called it creates a new global version of *printSize* with a closure to the value of *size* when it's called. So it will always report the last value passed to the constructor. In the *with* statement, it's the global *printSize* that's being called, the instances don't have a *printSize* method. Call `with(obj1) {update();}` again to see what happens. This code will fail in strict mode because of *with* and the undeclared *printSize*.